# Graphing Google results for various phrases

Tags: google-search

What is the easiest way to make graphs like these?

Is there an app for it?

[image]

http://xkcd.com/715/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for, but there's [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends). It shows you a graph of the average traffic of a set of phrases/keywords versus time. An example of what you can get is: http://www.google.com/trends?q=runescape,+world+of+warcraft